# Are there any simple and interesting conclusions from the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

The Collatz Conjecture here is the original conjecture.

For example, for which $n$'s we have $L(n)=L(n+1)$, where $L(n)$ is the steps needed to reach the integer 1 for the first time? I have examined the $n$'s from 1 to 100, and have found quite a number of them, but I can hardly find any pattern. The only verified form is

$$
n=8k+4, where\ k = 0, 1, 2, ...
$$

Of course, numbers of the form

$$
n=16k+4,\\
n=16k+12,\\
n=32k+20\\
...
$$

are some other forms, but they all can be treated as a special form of $n=8k+4$. So are there any other forms that don't exceed 100 and satisfy this property? To be exact, for the pattern $n=8k+4$, it requires only three steps of computation to show that $L(n)=L(n+1)$ since they both reach the same number. So I guess there's an interesting problem: given any positive integer $m$, for what positive constant integers $a, b$, integers $ak+b$ and $ak+b+1(k = 0, 1, 2, 3,...)$ will reach the same integer after at most $m$ steps?

Also, besides the question on consecutive numbers, are there any other interesting conclusions relevant to the Collatz conjecture that can be easily verified? Thank you!

Comment: consider the reverse mapping of Collatz.

Comment: I suppose you examined the original conjecture and not the shortcut one, since you did not mention it. I.e $3n+1$ for odd and $n/2$ for even. Well, my guess the reason there are many pairs is because of the evens and odds. Evens just have zero parity and so it will be divided until it gets odd. The problem of finding a pattern is because of the pattern is random. The odd to odd mapping shows this. You can see that the ruler function is fractal and is relevant to the highest exponent to the power of $2$ as denominator when dividing an even number into an odd number.

Comment: The problem finding the number of steps i.e. the stopping time is due to the randomness of the computations done to the numbers. Nobody has shown how to shortcut it without running a program until it reaches $1$. If somebody knew how to shortcut I think he/she might allready have a proof of the conjecture allready. I think those two are connected without me being able to show it.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Thank you for your answer, but I don't need to find all patterns; only a few nontrivial patterns will suffice. And for the pattern n=8k+4, it requires only three steps of computation to show that L(n)=L(n+1) since they both reach the same number! So I guess there's an interesting question: given any positive integer m, for what positive constant integers a, b,  integers ak+b and ak+b+1( k = 0, 1, 2, 3,...) will reach the same integer after at most m steps ?

Comment: Im unable to answer your last question, but it seems to be that $ak+b$ is same as generalized problem and Conway proved that its algorithmically undecidable. My own hobby research on the standard Collatz C. is that many patterns pop up when I've tried all possible ways to decode it. One of the hardest problem is the stopping time, but I haven't approached that directly. Anyways, wish you good luck on your journey. Also remember that even if the generalized problem is undecidable, it doesn't mean that the standard Collatz C is undecidable.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Sorry to reply to you after so many days. This is an exercise problem from "A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory", which is supposed to be an easy book. Maybe you have overestimated its difficulty, I wonder, haha.

Comment: That Collatz Conjecture is friendly can well be debated. heh.